# Find out which app is pushing ads in my notification bar?

Tags: notifications, ads

This may be a duplicate question but it seems the bad guy has improved its technology and known methods don't work so far. Anyway, started recently, my phone shows a notification every few days. Addons Detector and AirPush Detector didn't find anything related. Using:

```
adb shell dumpsys notification
```

I got this:

```
NotificationRecord{40c413b0 pkg=com.google.android.gsf id=1 tag=null}
  icon=0x1080077 / android:drawable/stat_notify_chat
  contentIntent=PendingIntent{40d4f178: PendingIntentRecord{40d62628 com.google.android.gsf startActivity}}
  deleteIntent=PendingIntent{40d4f148: PendingIntentRecord{40d45710 com.google.android.gsf broadcastIntent}}
  tickerText=xoxbellejenxo37@jabber-chat.com wants to be able to chat
  contentView=android.widget.RemoteViews@40cd0b38
  defaults=0x4
  flags=0x1
  sound=content://settings/system/notification_sound
  vibrate=null
  ledARGB=0x0 ledOnMS=0 ledOffMS=0
```

My question is what else can I do to find out which app is pushing ads? I don't want to try airpush opt out for two reasons:

1. I wouldn't trust people doing this at the first place.
2. I want to find out which app is doing this and add the company/developer behind it to my black list.

**UPDATE**

My phone is a rooted Samsung Captivate Glide, Android 2.3.

**UPDATE**

Updated to 4.0.4

Thanks

Comment: You might want to ask this also in stackoverflow.com Most of us here are only enthusiast that has limited programming/scripting knowledge to tackle your problem.

Comment: @forums this question is perfectly fine here, as it's an end-user's Android issue. It's not about programming (even though that *might* be the idea one gets due to the quote ;), so it would rather be OT at SO.

Comment: @Codism Could you please add the Android version you're on? Starting with JellyBean, you can follow the "ad" to its origin directly from the notification bar by long-pressing the notification and following the menu. You can even forbid specific apps to push ads there this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More and more developers are using these "marketing" methods of push notifications now that Google has their GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) service. The easiest way is to ask yourself the following questions:

- What Apps have I installed prior to receiving these notifications?
- What Apps have had updates around the time I started receiving these notifications?

Most of the time you will be able to figure out which app is doing it based on those questions and uninstall it.

If you cannot figure it out from that, you would have to start uninstalling apps one by one until you notice the notifications stop. If your only receiving them once every couple of days, this could be a real pain.

You MIGHT be able to get more information on which app is doing it by pulling the logcats off the phone, however I think the phone would need to be plugged in to a computer watching the logcats while it happened (I could be wrong on this, perhaps Android keeps the logs while not plugged in, but I do not have a for sure answer on this)

Answer (score 23):

Beginning with 4.1 Jelly Bean, you can long-press the notification itself. This will bring up a menu with a single item, "App Info". Touch this item and you will go straight to the offending app's management page, where you're just a touch away from "Force stop" and "Uninstall".

Comment: ... and, at least on 4.2, have the option of unchecking 'show notifications'

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer to help future readers of this post.